# pip3 is providing an error after installing the pygame module

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Used pip to install the pygame module and now I'm receiving this error any time I try to use any variation of the command:
`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: deprecated() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'



`

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip as well as rebooting my system.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+TypeError%3A+deprecated%28%29+got+an+unexpected+keyword+argument+name

Answer (score 1):

Try to uninstall pyOpenSSL, seens some kind of local conflict.

```
pip3 uninstall pyOpenSSL
```